# What is the use of documented protected properties is in framework classes?

Tags: c#

DataGridViewRowCollection has the following properties:

```
Count (public)
Gets the number of rows in the collection.

DataGridView (protected)
Gets the DataGridView that owns the collection.

Item (public)
Gets the DataGridViewRow at the specified index.

List (protected)
Gets an array of DataGridViewRow objects.
```

The question pops to my mind: how would I use these protected members?  I'm assuming they are taking up space in the documentation for a reason.

The scenario I can think of that I suppose could have use is deriving my own class and telling a DataGridView to use that class instead.

However, I don't know how to do that (maybe it's obvious and I just don't see it - that would be the answer here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into the inner workings of the protected properties you're referencing, you're assumption is correct: You could derive from DataGridViewRowCollection to implement some specialized functionality of your own.

I would assume you'd also have to override DataGridView to instance and use your DataGridViewRowCollection instead as well...

Answer (score 3):

Protected items can only be accessed from a more derived class. This means that if you create a `MyDataGridViewRowCollection`, which inherits from `DataGridViewRowCollection`, then you can access the `DataGridView` and `List` properties.

To create a class that inherits from DataGridViewRowCollection, you just do something along the lines of:

```
public class MyDataGridViewRowCollection : DataGridViewRowCollection
{
    public void MyMethod ()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridViewRowCollection` is not sealed and so you could inherit from it.  In this situation you would be able to call these methods, hence they have documentation.